# Recovering Oracle admin password

Tags: oracle

Are there any ways to recover oracle admins (sysman, sys,system) account in times of password forgetting, account locking out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/4399-oracle-recover-lost-passwords):

```
#sqlplus /nolog
SQL>conn / as sysdba
SQL>alter user Username identified by password;
```

According to [here](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/tools/orapwd.html) and [here](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/admin/password_file.html):

```
orapwd file=password_file_name password=the_secret_password entries=n
```

Comment: Which is fine as long as you haven't lost *all* of the admin accounts.

Comment: Not true. You can alter ANY account password this way.

Comment: +1, this works. Additionally, you can add the ACCOUNT UNLOCK option to the alter user command and unlock the account.